# How can I stop dockerd from using cgroups at all?

Tags: docker, cgroups

I want to run Docker containers on a system using cgroupv2 instead of cgroupv1, but Docker doesn't support cgroupv2 yet.

How can I configure `dockerd` to not use cgroups at all so that it will start?

Comment: Have you tried using systemd as a cgroup driver?

Comment: yeah, it complains about device cgroup not being mounted